# Why was that question about a database administration GUI closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I wonder why the following question got closed: [How can I disable the fade in and fade out effects in pgAdmin 4 when opening windows?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/143375/9622)

Aren't questions about database administration GUI on-topic here?

---

Here is the entire question:

> Title: How can I disable the fade in and fade out effects in pgAdmin 4 when opening windows?
>
> Is there any way to disable the fade in and fade out effects in
> pgAdmin 4 when opening windows?
>
> Example of fade in and fade out:
>
> [image]

[image]

Comment: Agree totally - DBA tools functionality questions are definitely on topic - yours isn't a "shopping list" question - it's very specific. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @Vérace: I agree as well but, to be fair, no-one said about it being a shopping list question.

Comment: My opinion is that this is not a about the functionality of a tool, but what looks like a UX related question. You're not asking about how to create indexes in pgAdmin, but how to remove a transition effect among screens. Maybe that helps your mood, which in turn helps you design better databases, but there's not a direct causation :).

Comment: @AndriyM I know that nobody gave that as a reason, but it's the usual cause of tool related questions being put on hold.

Comment: @Marian In my opinion any program-specific question helping the user to use the program more efficiently is okay.

Answer (score 1):

There was a difference of opinion on this one:

- The initial [close vote process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/close/73950) had two "Leave Open" dissenters.
- The [reopen process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/74187) had two "Leave Closed" dissenters.
- The question has two upvotes and no downvotes.

I added the [fifth Reopen vote](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/143375/revisions), so the question is now reopened to answers.

Comment: Tempted to vote for closing again, due to the disturbing gif.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Without that I would have eaten some unclear votes as well…

Answer (score 1):

I was one of the vote-to-closers but if I remember correctly the review queue was fairly big at the time, which may be a reason I didn't add a comment.

I admit I may have been a bit trigger-happy voting to close this as too localized, mainly because it's about beta software and the documentation or features might not be up to date yet. I believe you should file a bug report or raise it with the pgAdmin developers first. However the community seems to agree with you.

Since the question is reopened now I suppose you have done the right thing by raising it here and ask for the communities opinion, which according to @PaulWhite's answer still is divided.